# Как расшифровать данные DES ECB и TripleDES CBC?

Tags: безопасность, криптография, шифрование

Как расшифровать данные по алгоритму DES ECB и TripleDES CBC, имея шестнадцатибайтное значение и ключ?
Даны две пары шестнадцатибайтных значений и ключей (одна для алгоритма DES ECB, другая TripleDES CBC) как подступиться к расшифровке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одно из значений это ключ - для шифрования и дешифрования блока, а второе значение это т.н. инициализационный вектор (`IV` или `starting variable`) для `xor` операции перемешивания шифрованных блоков.

ECB и CBC называются модами шифрования или модами сцепления. В ECB по сути нет сцепления блоков и даже нет вектора, а в CBC есть сцепление блоков с перемешиванием вектора.

Более подробно [читайте здесь](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation)